# How to recover QR codes from Google Authenticator?

Tags: google-authenticator

I have used the smart switch program to backup my Galaxy S5 data. When I recover all the data the Google Authenticator app has lost all my QR codes.

Can I still recover the codes?

Comment: Have you wiped the S5 in between the backup and the restore? Seems obvious, but since you didn't mention it...

Comment: “Can I still recover the codes?” – Sure, using the rescue codes/other alternative access route that comes with any decent 2FA.

Comment: You can technically recover them - it's just data saved in your phone. Unfortunately the authenticator doesn't give you the ability to export it. You have to root the phone, and you can them dump the data. You'll have to Bing it to find it. I've never tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover your tokens if you saved QR codes or secret keys in the process of token enrollment. Also, some services offer recovery codes which can be used to recover access to your account. Then you will be able to issue the tokens on your new phone. If you didn’t save QR codes or secret keys and don’t know recovery codes you should contact the Support team of services which you protect with Google Authenticator. They will help you to restore an access to your accounts. Then you could issue new tokens.